# How to open developer promo page in Play Store using Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

There is links like that (Developer Promo page):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6599001017670379452

[image]

which is can be opened using

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

But I can't find way ***how to open it directly in Play Store*** without asking user to select between Browser and Play Store app.

This solution **NOT APPLICABLE** it opens search results:

```
market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.vending");
if (intent != null) {
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6599001017670379452"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```